# How can I make Log4j find my properties

Tags: java, properties, log4j

I've put my properties file in the resources directory in a maven project.
Then I look at it with the property configurator:
`PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");`

but I get the error log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in 2 ways

most probably that the file is contained in jar so

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties"));
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

if not

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("log4j.properties"));
PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```

or

in pom.xml you need to put the following

```
 <log4jProperties>path/log4j.properties</log4jProperties>
```

and under that path you need to create log4j.properties and write your configuration inside

Answer (score 0):

Try if you want to provide fixed path:-

```
Properties props = new Properties();

try {

    File file = new File("C:/log4j/log4j.properties");

    props.load(new FileInputStream(file));

} 

catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(KGLMainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

} 
catch (IOException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(KGLMainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
```